# Services window is always resetting view options

Tags: windows-7, windows

My Services window is resetting all the time.

I set it the way I like and when I close it and start again it is not how I set it up. Why is it saving Task Manager view settings and not Services?

Is there any way to make it remember my view settings for this window/application?

**The way I like it**

[image]

**Close it, open again and now it is ugly and unreadable again**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MMC has two modes: "author" and "user". When a MMC console is created, it can be configured to open in "user" mode which will lock down editing; there also is an option to ignore all changes done in "user" mode.

Make a **copy** of `%SystemRoot%\system32\services.msc` to your own folder (Desktop or wherever). Right-click it and select "Author". Adjust the interface to your needs, then use *File → Save*.

If you want to remove the restriction entirely, open the console in "author" mode, go to *File → Options*, and uncheck the "Do not save changes to this console" option. Click *OK* and use *File → Save* again. Afterwards, MMC will remember all modifications regardless of what mode you open the console in.

Comment: Thanks, I did it like that and saved it in my folder. I cannot, however, save it as original services.msc that is located in system32. Is there any way of modifying the original one?

Comment: There is, but **do not do that**. Let user preferences remain *user* preferences.